# vis.js network physicsConfiguration

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I am creating a network using vis.js and customizing my network with [physics configuration](http://visjs.org/examples/network/physics/physicsConfiguration.html)

```
physics:{
    stabilization: false,
},
configure: {
    filter:function (option, path) {
        if (path.indexOf('physics') !== -1) {
            return true;
        }
        if (path.indexOf('smooth') !== -1 || option === 'smooth') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
    showButton: false,
    container: document.getElementById('config')
},
```

[screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYsIG.png)

My problem is I do not want all the options, I just want some of the options and radio button only. How do I select only specific options or slider?

Thanks in advance

PS

As I [asked same question on github](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/2071) I have got the response as:

> Sorry but the only way would be to build your own config panel

you have to create your own config  pannel for the network

so if any one have any other idea of  customizing configuration of network plz share  highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

To adjust what options to show, you have just to adjust the `filter` function and actually filter options using the `option` and `path` params. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tjyvLbns/32/) I excluded the `forceDirection` option of `smooth` and left only `barnesHut` subset of options among `physics`:

```
configure: {
  filter:function (option, path) {
    if ((path.indexOf('physics') !== -1) && path.indexOf('barnesHut') !== -1) {
      //alert(path);
      return true;
    }
    if ((path.indexOf('smooth') !== -1 || option === 'smooth') && option != 'forceDirection') {
      //alert(option);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },
```

You may also uncomment `alert`s to explore values of `path` and `option` further (or use `console.log` for more convenience).